# Why do I get a "type mismatch" error when passing a function directly but it works with an equivalent closure?

Tags: rust

In my attempt to make my code a little bit cleaner, I tried passing the closure directly by name to the `map()` to an iterator for a `&[&str]`. map will need to iterate over `&&str` which is understandable but my closure only takes `&str`.

Code example:

```rust
fn capitalize_first(word: &str) -> String {
    word.chars().next().unwrap().to_uppercase().to_string()
}
fn main() {
    let cap_cap = |word: &&str| -> String {
        word.chars().next().unwrap().to_uppercase().to_string()
        };
    let a = ["we", "are", "testing"];

    let b = &a; // this is where this becomes interesting.
    
    b.iter().map(|&x| capitalize_first(x)); // Works
    b.iter().map(|x| capitalize_first(x));  // Works
    
    b.iter().map(cap_cap); // That's what the compiler expects.
    
    b.iter().map(capitalize_first); // fails to compile!
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:17:18
   |
1  | fn capitalize_first(word: &str) -> String {
   | ----------------------------------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> _`
...
16 |     b.iter().map(capitalize_first); // fails to compile!
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn(&&str) -> _`
```

A couple of questions:

1. Why does this work `map(|x| capitalize_first(x))` while `map(capitalize_first)` doesn't? What sort of magic happens behind the scenes in the first case? In my view, those should be identical.
2. Is there a reason on why rust can't transparently convert between `&&str` and `&str`?

Comment: Side note: you can use `.copied()` to convert an iterator of `&&str` to an iterator of `&str`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14d38ea378f597447fdc53cfbfb546b3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a reason on why rust can't transparently convert between `&&str` and `&str`?

Rust *does* transparently convert from `&&str` to `&str`, you can see it in one of your working examples:

```
b.iter().map(|x| capitalize_first(x))
           // ^ x is a &&str here ^ but seems to be a &str here
```

---

> What sort of magic happens behind the scenes[?]

The *"magic"* that happens is due to [type coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html), specifically [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion). *"Type coercions are implicit operations that change the type of a value"*.

---

> Why does this work `map(|x| capitalize_first(x))` while `map(capitalize_first)` doesn't?

What you've discovered is that while there is a coercion for `&&str` to `&str`, there is no coercion from `fn(&&str)` to `fn(&str)`. What coercions are available is pretty restricted.

On top of that, there are only specific places where coercion can occur, but what makes the first case work is that, with the closure, a *coercion site* is available right where you call `capitalize_first`:

```
b.iter().map(|x| capitalize_first(x))
                               // ^ the compiler injects code here to do the coercion 
                               //   as if you had written capitalize_first(*x)
```

When you use the function directly, there is no such site where coercion can occur.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think it's still reasonable to expect coercions of `fn(&&str)` to `fn(&str)` unless there are corner cases where there would result in unexpected behaviour. This practice is fairly common in functional languages and Rust borrows a lot of great ideas from those.

Comment: @AhmedFarghal The problem with such coercion is that `&&str` is not the same as `&str`, and `fn(&str)` is just a function pointer. When you have the function call in the closure, there is a well-defined place where the deref coercion happens. When you pass a function itself, then what you expect would require for the compiler to generate a _different_ function and use it as trampoline to the original function. If you (for some reason) compared the addresses of the received function to a known one, you'd not get the function you passed, and so on. This was probably deemed too magical.

Comment: @user4815162342: Arguably, comparing pointers to functions is opening a can-of-worms, I'm not sure it is even guaranteed - think inlining, dynamic linking, generics... And the compiler could be made to insert the conversion from `f` to `|x| f(x)` automatically. Not that I'm arguing that it would be a good idea, but it would be _possible_.

Comment: @rodrigo I agree it would be possible, I just wanted to point out that the function coercion is not just a trivial type-system-level hack, it entails generating an actual new function and using it instead of the requested one. I agree that comparing function pointers is a fairly sketchy technique (though [not unheard-of](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/37272f5800ee1e9fcb2da4a1766366519b9b3d94/Objects/typeobject.c#L5940) in systems programming); it was not meant as proof that the feature is impossible, but that it's not without consequences to observable behavior.